# Fragments nested do not appear after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this situation,

*Activity -> RestaurantsFragment -> [viewPager / FragmentPageAdapter] Two Fragments*

I want to retain all the fragments after the screen rotation but what happens is that

- the Activity is correctly destroyed and recreated
- the RestaurantsFragment is correctly retained and reattached to the activity
- **the two fragments do not appear. Their methods onAttach, onCreateView etc...are not invoked**

Here is my code...

Activity.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ....

    if (savedInstanceState== null) {
        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMNET_RESTAURANTS);
        if(fragment==null) {
            fragment = new RestaurantsFragment();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, (TAG_FRAGMNET_RESTAURANTS);

    }

    ....
  }
```

RestaurantsFragment.java

```
    private TabsRestaurantsAdapter tabsRestaurantsAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int position;


  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Luigi-RFragment-" + id, "onCreate");

        setRetainInstance(true);


        Log.d("Luigi-RFragment-" + id, "savedInstanceState==null");
        tabsRestaurantsAdapter = new TabsRestaurantsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Luigi-RFragment-" + id, "onCreateView");

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ristoranti_fragment, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsRestaurantsAdapter);

        position = 0;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position");
        }

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("position", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }
```

TabsRestaurantsAdapter.java

```
public class TabsRestaurantsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String titles[] = new String[]{"I TUOI PREFERITI", "TUTTI"};
    private MenusFavTabFragment menusFavTabFragment;
    private RestaurantsAllTabFragment restaurantsAllTabFragment;

    public TabsRestaurantsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        menusFavTabFragment = new MenusFavTabFragment();
        restaurantsAllTabFragment = new RestaurantsAllTabFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Log.d("Luigi-adapter", "getItem" + index);
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Favourite Fragment
                return menusFavTabFragment;

            case 1:
                // All Restaurant
                return restaurantsAllTabFragment;

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment f = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        return f;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return titles.length;
    }

}
```

Consider that when the RestaurantsFragment is reattached, the adapter (old) is setted again in the viewPager and the method of the adapter *instantiateItem* is invoked

The two fragments nested have nothing special

*( I have also tried to recreate a new adapter each time (managing thre reuse of the old fragments) and it works but only for one rotation...but why should i recreate the adapter ? )*

Why they do not appear?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bug in the support library v4.

For more info [Nested fragments not being retained in support library](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74222).

Personally, I do the nasty thing of setting the configuration changes on my manifest to `orientation` and `screenSize`. I didn't give myself a time to think of a better way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Thanks Thanks @hegazy

I discovered and applyed this workaround and now it works:

*retain the childFragmentManager and reassign it to the Field object*

the new **RestaurantsFragment.java**

```
    //the global childFragmentManager
    private FragmentManager mRetainedChildFragmentManager;

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        //To fix the bug with library v4
        if (mRetainedChildFragmentManager != null) {
            //restore the last retained child fragment manager to the new
            //created fragment
            try {
                Field childFMField = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
                childFMField.setAccessible(true);
                childFMField.set(this, mRetainedChildFragmentManager);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            mRetainedChildFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        }

    }
```

I hope this can help you !

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed in the support library version 24.

The call to onAttach() shown in the workaround was causing a NPE in the containing activity's super.onCreate() method during rotation. On a whim, I removed the onAttach() code since this NPE only occurred in the Activity/Fragment where I had implemented the solution. After removing the call to onAttach(), the NPE went away and it appears as though my code is working as expected.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197271